# scala: pass tuple reference to function

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, tuples, pyspark

In python I can simply define one function like this:

```
def func(lst):  
   lst[0] = lst[0] + 5  
   return lst
```

This 'lst' can take list of different lengths as argument.

How do I do it in Scala using tuples?

Note: I am trying to implement a Spark program (or general purpose library) in Scala which is written in Python. In that program there is this function which takes each record from the RDD as an argument, operates on it and then returns it. Now the length of these records can vary depending upon which RDD the function is called on.

Answer (score 2):

The exact equivalent to a python function you are describing would look something like this this:

```
 def func(list: List[Any]) =  list.headOption.map { 
  _.asInstanceOf[Int] + 5 
 } ++ list.tail
```

But don't do it. Type safety (being able to ensure at the compile time that the data you are looking at is exactly of the type you expect it to be) is one of the biggest reasons to pick scala over python to begin with.

If you don't intend to make use of that, why bother rewriting your python code in scala? Just use what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
def add5ToHead(list: List[Int]) = {
  list match {
    case head :: tail => head+5 :: tail
    case l => l
  }
}
```

Comment: Only problem is the elements of the _List/Tuple_ can be of different types. So it has to be a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The `copy` method could be a good fit for your case:

```
def func1(t: (Int, Int, Int)) = t.copy(_1 = t._1 + 5)
```

`Int` type and `+5` is just an example, you can pass in the value and type via extra arguments.

You could also apply a `PartialFunction` to your method, eg:

```
val partialFunc1: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case x => x + 5
}

def func1(t: (Int, Int, Int), f: PartialFunction[Int, Int]) = t.copy(_1 = f(t._1))

func1((1,2,3), partialFunc1) // output will be (6,2,3)
```